# scrollToRowAtIndexPath checks for indexpath before my tableview is set up

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using the scrollToRowAtIndexPath to center my tableview on the previously selected cell, however its crashing the app while testing on the phone but not on the emulator.

This is how I set it up

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //Center previously selected cell to center of the screen
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:oldCheckedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
}
```

And this is the error its giving

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: section (0) beyond bounds (0).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31fe88bf 0x31d581e5 0x31fe87b9 0x31fe87db 0x32b6df1f 0x29bef 0x32ae26b5 0x32b3daf1 0x32afed21 0x32afea71 0x32afe78b 0x32afe4ff 0x32ab581b 0x32abafb9 0x3193aba7 0x3273be8d 0x31fbb2dd 0x31f3e4dd 0x31f3e3a5 0x3204afed 0x32ace743 0x34f5 0x2f70)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

The thing being is I set

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:oldCheckedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
```

in a different method the application works fine but dose not scroll to the index position..
I dont know how to fix it.

UPdate New error when trying to delay scrollToRowAtIndexPath

```
2011-11-02 16:00:58.180 code[2303:707] -[VehicleResultViewController methodThatCallsScrollToRow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f3410
2011-11-02 16:00:58.184 code[2303:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VehicleResultViewController methodThatCallsScrollToRow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f3410'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31fe88bf 0x31d581e5 0x31febacb 0x31fea945 0x31f45680 0x35bef943 0x31fbca63 0x31fbc6c9 0x31fbb29f 0x31f3e4dd 0x31f3e3a5 0x3204afed 0x32ace743 0x34a9 0x2f24)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't need to reload data - just run your scrollToRowAtIndexPath after a delay:

[self performSelector:@selector(methodThatCallsScrollToRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];

Give the table a chance to load.

Comment: weird.. I have no idea why this is happening but after putting that line of code in I started getting error I have added above every time I try to access the subview.

Comment: lol bloody hell! lol **methodThatCallsScrollToRow** lol.. thats whats c ausing the error.. the thing being is that the scroll code is inside viewDidAppear method

Comment: AWESOME! worked perfectly! you my friend deserve a high five! lol taken me all day to track the actual problem down.. and this solved it nicely I dropped the time down to 0.5 and it animates nicely. I think I will add a small loading thingy to get this really looking right for the user.... very cool thanks

Comment: Seems very hackish and could cause a race condition between the table reload. This seems to be the 'better' way of doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16071589/82976

Comment: @JayQ. The method given above is functionally the same as the second method (dispatch_async) and was written prior to that answer.

Comment: @owen Specifying a delay is different from waiting for the main thread. performSelector works differently from GCD.

Comment: @JayQ. The delay is arbitrary, could be 0.0. At any rate, your main thread will get called.  performSelector is functionally identical to dispatch_async.

Comment: Hi @JayQ - that's comparing dispatch_sync to performSelectorOnMainThread. I'm comparing dispatch_async to performSelector.  There may be some slight differences in Apple's implementation, but it should provide the same result.